What are the legal implications when sending an invitation letter for somebody applying for the Schengen visa?
Suppose the following hypothetical scenarios:

Alice coming to visit Bob, requires a Schengen visa.
Alice registered for an international event organised by Bob's Company and needs a Schengen visa.

I understand that Alice would need an invitation letter in both cases.
What legal implications would Bob, or Bob's company, have when sending Alice the invitation letter to help her get the Schengen visa?

You might get more prompt and knowledgeable answers by posting in [travel.se]. That's where all the visa-related experts seem to hang out.

Since that is matter of National Law (and not Schengen/EU law), you would need to state the country

@NicolasFormichella I don't think there are any big differences between the countries, but let's assume that Bob (and Bob's Company) is located in Poland (EU) and Alice is from India.

There are big differences, for example in Italy, for the sponsor to bear all costs, the sponsor has to lock a lump sum in a bank account (fideiussione bancaria)
